# How do I go about geting synergy 100% operational with error in build process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, synergy, arduino

During the install process I get the following snippet of an error When I get to the part about cryptopp:
Scanning dependencies of target cryptopp

```
[ 19%] Building CXX object ext/CMakeFiles/cryptopp.dir/cryptopp562/3way.cpp.o
In file included 

from /home/ubuntu/Downloads/synergy-1.6.2-Source/ext/cryptopp562/stdcpp.h:12:0,

from /home/ubuntu/Downloads/synergy-1.6.2-Source/ext/cryptopp562/cryptlib.h:83,

from /home/ubuntu/Downloads/synergy-1.6.2-Source/ext/cryptopp562/seckey.h:8,

from /home/ubuntu/Downloads/synergy-1.6.2-Source/ext/cryptopp562/3way.h:7,

from /home/ubuntu/Downloads/synergy-1.6.2-Source/ext/cryptopp562
/3way.cpp:5:

/usr/include/stdlib.h: In function ‘double atof(const char*)’:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:279:1: sorry, unimplemented: Thumb-1 hard-float VFP ABI
make[2]: *** [ext/CMakeFiles/cryptopp.dir/cryptopp562/3way.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/CMakeFiles/cryptopp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

At which point it returns to my previous folder as is the default behavior for linux. The machine is a pcDuino v3 with 4gb NAND memory and soon I will be receiving a 32 GB micro sd card to store more items (files and folders) on the lubuntu 12.10 or 12.11 that I have installed. I plan to run it as client or server, I have two Plus two hewlwtt packard laptops that I've been able to install successfully synergy 1.6.2. 1 pcduino equals server 1 pcduino equals client 2 HP laptops equals 4 clients * each laptop may or may not have Vmware running and the virtual machine might have synergy installed.so therefor 1 server 5 clients

Comment: Did you try googling the error? are you cross compiling? http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=8758 *seems* to be similar to your current issue.